# Layer style is not rendered properly using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-2, rendering

I'm trying to render a layer with the given .qml style into .png image using a standalone PyQGIS application. The issue is that not all the layers of the symbology are rendered, e.g. a polygon with the colour fill, pattern fill and the svg-marker outline will be rendered with only colour fill, but pattern fill and svg-marker outline will be missing. And during execution of the script I get this (seems to be Qt-error) message: `QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 3`. Tried to google this error but found nothing helpful. QGIS 2.14.

The code:

```
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSize
from PyQt4.QtGui import QPainter, QImage, QColor

qgisApp = QgsApplication([], False)
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath('/usr', True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()
print QgsApplication.showSettings()


lyr = QgsVectorLayer('bbox.shp', 'bbox', 'ogr')
lyr_id = lyr.id()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(lyr)
lyr.loadNamedStyle( 'bbox.qml')


# create image
img = QImage(QSize(800, 600), QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied)

# set image's background color
# color = QColor(255, 255, 255)
# img.fill(color.rgb())

# create painter
p = QPainter()
p.begin(img)
p.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

layers = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers()
lst = layers.keys()
print 'lst', lst
renderer = QgsMapRenderer()
renderer.setLayerSet(lst)

extent = renderer.fullExtent()
rect = QgsRectangle(extent)
# print rect.toString()
rect.scale(1.1)
renderer.setExtent(rect)

# set output size
renderer.setOutputSize(img.size(), img.logicalDpiX())

# do the rendering
renderer.render(p)
p.end()

# save image
img.save('test.png', 'png')

QgsApplication.exitQgis()
```

A test layer and style can be downloaded [here](http://gis-lab.info/forum/download/file.php?id=12004).